# Bootstrap Placing Asterisk next to input textbox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap grid system and I am trying to figure out how I can place a red asterisk behind my input box (right to the right of it) with not much spacing. To show that input box as being required.

I am unable to figure out bootstraps gird system to do so. I've tried putting it as the label but it puts it on top. As a span it puts it below. How can I put this just right behind the input?

```
    <div id="propertyidsearch">
        <div class="col-lg-3 required">
            <input type="text" name="searchValue" maxlength="2000" size="40" value="" class="form-control input-sm">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default margin-bottom-10" id="name" name="name">OWNER NAME</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default margin-bottom-10" id="location" name="location">PROPERTY ADDRESS</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default margin-bottom-10" id="billingAddress" name="billingAddress">BILLING ADDRESS</button>
        </div>
    </div>

.required:after{
  content:"*";
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: I also tried putting required in the class of input. I am doing the same thing as whats being marked for duplicate question so just looking for a little help getting it to work.

Comment: just try my answer, dude

Comment: ...or the duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Twitter Bootstrap the grid system doesn't only work once for the entire width of your page, but also within individual `col` blocks, ie. once you define `col-lg-3` you then have an additional 12 `col` blocks inside that block dividing the space into 12 smaller parts. Use it whichever way you like, ie dividing 8-4 (as in the below example - I recommend opening the snippet in Full page view), or any other, just make sure it's 12 in total.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div id="propertyidsearch">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
         <div class="col-lg-8">
             <input type="text" name="searchValue" maxlength="2000" size="40" value="" class="form-control input-sm">
           </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4">
             <span style="color:red;">*</span>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default margin-bottom-10" id="name" name="name">OWNER NAME</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default margin-bottom-10" id="location" name="location">PROPERTY ADDRESS</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default margin-bottom-10" id="billingAddress" name="billingAddress">BILLING ADDRESS</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can play with it here: http://www.bootply.com/eV4qRJT14V

Comment: theres just such a huge gap on this :(

Comment: read my edit... you can change it to 10-2 for example, play with it here: http://www.bootply.com/eV4qRJT14V